# Responsive background image with 7 divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I already made this design in plain html and css. [image]

It is a whole background image with a 7 divs that occupy with text on its center.

here is the code and however can I make this responsive as window size change,  because it will break if window change happen. I am just using plain css. not even bootstrap. Any help and assistance will be a great help me. Thanks.

**HTML**

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
}

#main {
  background-image: url("./girl-jump.png"); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 452px;
  width: 1021px; 
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

#first {
  height: 452px;
  width: 234px;
  float:left; 
  border-right:2px solid white;
}

#second {
  height: 225px;
  width: 263px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

#third {
  height: 225px;
  width: 263px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

#fourth {
  height: 225px;
  width: 261px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  border-bottom:1px solid white;
}

#fifth {
  height: 227px;
  width: 263px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  border-top:1px solid white;
}


#six {
  height: 225px;
  width: 263px;
  overflow:hidden;  
  float:left;
  border-right:2px solid white;
  border-top:1px solid white;
}

#seventh {
  height: 225px;
  width: 261px;
  overflow:hidden; 
  border-right:2px solid white; 
  border-top:1px solid white;
}

.center-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.center-text {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">
  <p class="center-text">Excellence</p>
  </div>  

  <div id="second">
    <p class="center-text">Quality</p>
  </div>  


  <div id="third">
      <p class="center-text">Efficiency</p>
  </div>  

   <div id="fourth">
      <p class="center-text">Creativity</p>
  </div>  


  <div id="fifth">
      <p class="center-text">Faith</p>
  </div>  


  <div id="six">
      <p class="center-text">Effectiveness</p>
  </div>

  <div id="seventh">
      <p class="center-text">Teamwork</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmg6pzLy/)

Comment: Make a working snippet

Comment: Yes, you can make it responsive. It's quite simple, actually: Place the image as background of your container. Draw the transparent divs with 1px borders and negative left margin of 1px responsively over it. I suggest using flexbox, but that's entirely up to you. One of the most basic rules on [so] is that you need to make an attempt at the task yourself before asking for help.

Comment: a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVaodK

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i have not tried flexbox, maybe I can research about that

Comment: It could be responsive but i’m not sure it would be ergonomic on small device.

Comment: Yes I got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to flex and avoid using fixed values like this :

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  background-image: url("https://lorempixel.com/800/800/");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.part {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

#first {
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
}

#second,
#third,
#fourth,
#fifth,
#seventh,
#six {
  flex: 1;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  align-items:center;
  display:flex;
  
}


.center-text {
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="first">
    <p class="center-text">Excellence</p>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <div id="second">
      <p class="center-text">Quality</p>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
      <p class="center-text">Efficiency</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <div id="fourth">
      <p class="center-text">Creativity</p>
    </div>
    <div id="fifth">
      <p class="center-text">Faith</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="part">
    <div id="six">
      <p class="center-text">Effectiveness</p>
    </div>
    <div id="seventh">
      <p class="center-text">Teamwork</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your idea. I really appreacate it. Iwill try iy

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you're looking for. Note I used `min-aspect-ratio` media query to account for presence of scrollbar but this assumes:

- `#main` is the only element of your page (which is probably not the case)
- the scrollbar takes up exactly 17px (as in Chrome and Firefox), on non-touch devices

Most likely, you want to remove that query, especially if you don't care about the absolute 1/1 ratio of width/height of your boxes. If you do, you'll probably way safer detecting touch devices and aspect ratio using javascript, specifically Modernizr.

I used flex for centering content of each box, but kept the floats for the boxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray
}

#main {
  background: black url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x400") no-repeat center center /cover; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

#main > * {
  width: calc((100% / 4) - 1px);
  height: calc((100vw / 4) - 1px);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
#main > *:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main > *:first-child {
  height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
@media  (min-aspect-ratio: 2/1)  { 
  #main > * {
    height: calc((100vw / 4) - 5px);
  }
  #main > *:first-child {
    height: calc((100vw / 2) - 9px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div> Excellence </div>
  <div> Quality </div>
  <div> Efficiency </div>
  <div> Creativity </div>
  <div> Faith </div>
  <div> Effectiveness </div>
  <div> Teamwork </div>
</div>
```

Not sure why, but I assumed you want your boxes to be squares, so I rolled with it. If you want their height to always be half of screen height, here's how I'd do it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray
}

#main {
  background: black url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x400") no-repeat center center /cover; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

#main > * {
  width: calc((100% / 4) - 1px);
  height: calc(50vh - 0.5px);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
#main > *:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main > *:first-child {
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div> Excellence </div>
  <div> Quality </div>
  <div> Efficiency </div>
  <div> Creativity </div>
  <div> Faith </div>
  <div> Effectiveness </div>
  <div> Teamwork </div>
</div>
```

Please note none of proposed solutions distort the background image. It just fits it best to `cover` `#main` and crops the excess.

---

But let's get back to what responsive means. Responsive doesn't mean your images scale down on mobile. It means your content is accessible and usable on mobile. So you probably want to divide the columns from four to two and display them below each other so the content remains readable, on really narrow devices. Say... under 540px width:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray
}

#main {
  background: black url("https://source.unsplash.com/random/1000x400") no-repeat center center /cover; 
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

#main > * {
  width: calc((100% / 4) - 1px);
  height: calc((100vw / 4) - 1px);
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: -1px -1px 0 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
#main > *:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#main > *:first-child {
  height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 539px) {
  #main>* {
    width: calc((100% / 2) - 1px);
    height: calc((100vw / 2) - 1px);
  }
  #main>*:first-child {
    height: calc(100vw - 1px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div> Excellence </div>
  <div> Quality </div>
  <div> Efficiency </div>
  <div> Creativity </div>
  <div> Faith </div>
  <div> Effectiveness </div>
  <div> Teamwork </div>
</div>
```

This would be what I call *responsive*.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying and sharing. its great even though I have not try flex and aspect ratio

Comment: Can I follow up? How can I make the part of the div id "first" black and  white when hover?

Comment: Normally you are not supposed to ask new questions in existing ones, because that only helps you, not future visitors. But that's quite easy. `#main>*:hover {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.35)}`. I'll update the first example with a solution that does the change smoothly. I updated both. :)

Comment: WOW A big thanks to you buddy really great help I appreciate it its works like charm

Comment: Hi again, I was putting the html and css in wordpress (visual composer raw html widget), but it seems like the flex is acting strange, does it require some code?

Comment: Hello! I like to ask what I need to change in CSS if I want to put "EXCELLENCE" part on the right instead in left

Comment: Considering the example, all you need is `float:right` on `:first-child`. I updated the last snippet to show.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Thanks for corresponding!!. Can I ask some again? coz I am still learning the FLEX method and I am wondering what I need to if I want to put EXCELLENCE in the second column

Comment: You'd need to change the markup (html) and group them differently for that. You want at least 2 columns. One of them should have the tall item to either right or left. No intention to be rude here, but, again, nobody except you is benefiting from these questions, as they are not indexed. And I'm not entirely sure if you wouldn't benefit more if you asked less and coded more, making mistakes. A good mistake can teach you more than 10 teachers.